# Saving ASP.NET Chart to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I try to save image from ASP.NET chart control to pdf.
I've found this solution on the Internet:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
    chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
    pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Chart.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

But when i run this code nothing happens (window with question where to save PDF won't appear).

In web.config i have this:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=session;timeout=360;" />
```

I cannot save file with defined file path.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with following-

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
        Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
        chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
        pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Chart.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(pdfDoc);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
}
```

Also, I have found `pdfDoc.Close();` this line. Is it really necessary to close it.(Try removing it if not necessary)

Comment: Still the same. I had to replace Response.WriteFile with Response.Write because there was error. I removed the pdfDoc.Close() - same effect :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace your this line

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
```

with

```
System.IO.MemoryStream msReport = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
```

and

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

with

```
Response.BinaryWrite(msReport.ToArray());
```

hope this solve your problem